# What is the difference between 10 m/s and 10 m/s-1

Tags: problem-solving

So i'm struggling to understand what the difference is between 10m/s and 10m/s–1 .The question was a runner runs 100m in 10 seconds what is their velocity.Does putting a -1 after m/s change anything or is that the proper formant.

Comment: For a velocity you may say $10\, m/s$ or $10\, ms^{-1}$. Note that $s^{-1}=\frac{1}{s}$

Answer (score 3):

If we're talking about velovities, then it's $ms^{-1}$, not $m/s^{-1}$. And no, there is no difference at all between $ms^{-1}$ and $m/s$, as $s^{-1}$, by definition of $^{-1}$, is exactly the same as $1/s$.

It's a matter of aesthetic preference.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what $ 10 \text{ } m/s - 1$ means. Neither $10 \text{ } \dfrac{m}{s} - 1$ Nor $10 \text{ } \dfrac{m}{s-1}$ makes sense in this context as you can't take a unit less value from one with units.

$ 10 \text{ } m/s $ means $10 \text{ } \dfrac{m}{s}$ or a cyclist travels 10 meters every second.

You may be getting confused with $10 \text{ } ms^{-1}$ Which means the same as $10 \text{ } \dfrac{m}{s} = 10 \text{ }m/s$ so is equivalent.

While $10 \text{ } m/s^{-1} = 10 \text{ } \dfrac{m}{s^{-1}} = 10 \text{ }ms$.  This is quite different.